# oraclize calling a REST API

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, oracles

I am trying to call a third party REST API that I developed using spring boot, and I want to call a `function(param1,param2)` in the API from the oracle using the `oraclize_query()` (POST request), but I kind of don't know how to pass the parameters in `oraclize_query()`!!

Answer (score 1):

To pass POST requests from Oraclize, you can pass an additional parameter as the data you want to POST.

Example:

```
oraclize_query("URL","json(https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes).status",
              '{"postcodes" : ["OX49 5NU", "M32 0JG", "NE30 1DP"]}');
```

...where the additional passed (`'{"postcodes" : ["OX49 5NU", "M32 0JG", "NE30 1DP"]}'`) represents POST data.

Your API's route manager should pass the proper parameters to the function.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but I want to pass some variables and not static data in the query, do you have any idea how to do so.

Comment: @ELIdrissiYazamiYounes At the end of the day, the data you pass has ends up in some static form. Consider converting the data to a string before passing the data.